# Django show static image based on model value

Tags: html, django

I have a `DetailView` in Django that gets the input from a model instance. I also have an images folder at the path `static/images/nba_players` containing a picture for each player in the format playername.jpg (ie; russellwestbrook.jpg)

Now, say in the `DetailView` the model instance has the player attribute "Russell Westbrook." How can I get the HTML to find the picture for the player represented in the model instance? My initial thought is to strip the player name string of spaces and capital letters in `views.py` and pass it in as context data. But then I still don't know how in the HTML to reference that specific image. Any help would be great.

Comment: you can't do `<img src="/static/images/nba_players/{{ player.name }}.jpg">` or similar?

Comment: read this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/django-static-files-handling get some idea, try something out and post the code where you are stuck or get any error. This way its easy to help you out.